# Who am I to balance nothing?

Tags: riddle

> If I stand up, I am balancing nothing.
>   If I split in the middle, my left would phonetically talk like a parrot, and my right would be lifted as a cube.
>   If I lie down, I can wait forever.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> The number 8

If I stand up, I am balancing nothing:

> An 8 looks like 0 (nothing) balancing on another 0.

If I split in the middle, my left would phonetically talk like a parrot:

> The left side of the 8 becomes an E, which is represented by the codeword 'echo' in the International Radiotelephony Spelling Alphabet. Parrots often repeat (or echo) whatever they hear.

And my right would be lifted as a cube:

> The right side of the 8 becomes the number 3. If you lift this number, it becomes an exponent, and represents the cube of a given number.

If I lie down, I can wait forever:

> If an 8 is turned on its side, it becomes the sign representing infinity (forever is an infinite time into the future).

Comment: Awesome riddle and an awesome answer +1 :)